# Why does the compiler not recognize my return statements?

Tags: java, string, methods, boolean, logic

I have the following chunk of code:

```
public static boolean isReverse (String s1, String s2) {    
    if((s1.length()==1)&&s2.length()==1) {          
        if(s1.equals(s2)) {             
            return true;
        }
    }       
    else if(s1.charAt(0)==s2.charAt(s2.length()-1)) {           
        return isReverse(s1.substring(1, s1.length()-1),s2.substring(0, s2.length()-2));
    }       
    else return false;  
}
```

I understand that normally you need a return statement to cover the possibility of none of the if statements being true. That is why I have the `else return false` at the end, but I still get the error "must return a result of type boolean". Here is the call that I am using it from:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(isReverse("Java", "avaJ")) {
        System.out.println("worked");
    }
}
```

Comment: change `else return false` to `return false`. You are missing a return path due to that `else`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first `if` there is a possibility that there will not be a return statement:

```
if((s1.length()==1)&&s2.length()==1) {
    //What if this is not true?
    if(s1.equals(s2)) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

In this block if `s1` does not equal `s2` then it will step out of the `if` and since the last `return false;` is linked to the `else` block, it will reach the end of the method with nothing to return.

To fix this instead of `else return false`, simply `return false;`

Answer (score 2):

The first `if` has a nested `if` condition, which leads to a branch where you return nothing. You could remove the last `else` and make it `return false;` by default. Or simply modify the nested `if` **into** a `return` itself. That is, change this

```
if((s1.length()==1)&&s2.length()==1) {
    if(s1.equals(s2)) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

to just (re-indented and supraflous parens removed)

```
if (s1.length() == 1 && s2.length() == 1) {
    return s1.equals(s2);
}
```

We could also reimplement the method with a `StringBuilder` in one line, like

```
public static boolean isReverse(String s1, String s2) {
    return new StringBuilder(s1).reverse().toString().equals(s2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isReverse (String s1, String s2) {    
    if(s1.length()==1&&s2.length()==1) {          
        if(s1.equals(s2)) {             
            return true;
        } else {
            return false; // This portion need to be return some result.
        }
    }       
    else if(s1.charAt(0)==s2.charAt(s2.length()-1)) {           
        return isReverse(s1.substring(1, s1.length()-1),s2.substring(0, s2.length()-2));
    }       
    else return false;  
}
```

Or

```
public static boolean isReverse (String s1, String s2) {    
    if(s1.length()==1&&s2.length()==1) {          
        if(s1.equals(s2)) {             
            return true;
        }
    }       
    else if(s1.charAt(0)==s2.charAt(s2.length()-1)) {           
        return isReverse(s1.substring(1, s1.length()-1),s2.substring(0, s2.length()-2));
    }       
    return false;  // Just return the result without else
}
```